# Using POI to find out format for a cell

Tags: apache-poi

What is the correct way to get the `CellFormatType` for a cell (`DATE`, `NUMBER`, `TEXT`, `GENERAL`) ?

`cell.getCellStyle.getDataFormat()` returns a Short value, which does not map to the above constants.

I cannot just use `cell.getCellType` for the following reason. For certain rows, there may be a string prefix like `<>` or `>` in front of the value. In that case, `getCellType` will return `CELL_TYPE_STRING`. So the only way to get the underlying type appears to be to look at the format for the column.

Thanks

Comment: Excel lets you format a cell as many hundreds of different formats - it's way way more than just the 4 you've specified!

Comment: Thanks, but am only interested in the basic types, String, Number, Date. Have edited the question to explain why.So if I can find the way to get the CellFormatType, should be able to look at which range the value fall in.

Comment: In fact, the online doc for CellFormatType Enum Constant Summary only lists four values.

Comment: If a cell is a String cell, then that's the format. You can't format a string

Comment: Not exactly true. Even if the content is a String, the cell can still be formatted as a date. Of course, the format would not be applied because the content is not a date. But that format info is still stored, and for my use case, where the column would represent date values, but some dates will be stored as strings (because of the prefix), that's very important. It tell me that the string really represents a date, so I can handle the string correctly in the code. Right now I have to rely on cell.getCellStyle.getDataFormat - would like to get the CellFormatType enumeration directly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a direct route from `Cell` to `CellFormatType`, but there are various ways to determine particular types:

- General? `getDataFormat` will be 0 (or more reliably, `getDataFormatString` will be "General")
- Date? Check out [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell))
- Text? Typically you'd check for [Cell.getCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType()) = `CELL_TYPE_STRING`, but since you say you can't do this (see comments below), you could also try checking if `getDataFormatString` is "@" or "text" (both are possibilities for plain text)
- Number? Again, usually you'd just check for `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`. Note that dates are also considered numbers, so check for dates first.

(If the cell type is `CELL_TYPE_FORMULA` you should check `getCachedFormulaResultType` instead)

> I cannot just use cell.getCellType for the following reason. For certain rows, there may be a string prefix like <> or > in front of the value

I'm not familiar with this problem. Perhaps you have a custom format which prepends characters before the number? My notes on text detection above might help you in this case, but I suggest you double-check that your spreadsheet actually has the relevant information (i.e. it isn't just Excel being clever when you re-open the sheet): log the cell type, format and format string, and confirm that there actually is a difference on the relevant cells. It's possible that your cell is actually being saved as text, with no distinguishing mark. In this case, you'll need to add some special heuristics for your specific scenario.

---

Finally, since you seem confused about the returned value from `CellStyle.getDataFormat`; it's just an index in a sheet-wide index → format-string table. You can (and I'd say usually should) use `getDataFormatString` to get the string format directly. The standard cell formats are listed in [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html), which you can use as a reference to see which format strings you might find (but always check the format string, not the ID, otherwise you'll fail to detect custom formats correctly).